# Printing a str in an array corresponding to an array next to it if element fulfils condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a (12, 2) Numpy array, with col 0 being an array of strings and col 1 being an nd.array.

For each element in col 1, if it is > 100, then I'd like it to print the str in the string array next to it.

```
print(table)
[['Jan' '1765.869']
 ['Feb' '1337.9730000000002']
 ['Mar' '-2595.4530000000004']
 ['Apr' '-2040.0169999999996']
 ['May' '-419.944']
 ['Jun' '5085.668']
 ['Jul' '5747.385']
 ['Aug' '2761.479']
 ['Sep' '2329.8729999999996']
 ['Oct' '-1567.055000000001']
 ['Nov' '461.71999999999895']
 ['Dec' '8140.678']]
```

[image]

After an hour of searching for what might be the right way to access each element, I've come up with the following statements:

```
for i in table[:,1]:
    if i > 100:
        print(table[i,:1])
```

But ran into these errors:

In Jupyter Notebook:`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.str_'`

In Spyder: `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Would appreciate any help on this, if possible without doing this in Pandas cos I'd like to use this as an opportunity to improve on my numpy skills.

Comment: Can you post you actual array as python code rather than an image?

Comment: Just edited post with it. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try iterating through the array in pairs:

```
x = np.array([['Jan', '1765.869'],
 ['Feb', '1337.9730000000002'],
 ['Mar', '-2595.4530000000004'],
 ['Apr', '-2040.0169999999996'],
 ['May', '-419.944'],
 ['Jun', '5085.668'],
 ['Jul', '5747.385'],
 ['Aug', '2761.479'],
 ['Sep', '2329.8729999999996'],
 ['Oct', '-1567.055000000001'],
 ['Nov', '461.71999999999895'],
 ['Dec', '8140.678']])

for mon, num in x:
    if float(num) > 100:
        print(mon)
```

This results in

```
Jan
Feb
Jun
Jul
Aug
Sep
Nov
Dec
```

**Edit**: To approach your max value determination, since you are already looping through all items, it would be simplest to just keep track of the max value and the month corresponding to this max:

```
max_val = 0
max_month = ''
for mon, num in x:
    val = float(num)
    if val > 100:
        print(mon)
    if val > max_val:
        max_val = val
        max_month = mon

print(max_month)
```

Or, you could use a one-liner:

```
print(max([(float(num), mon) for mon, num in x])[1])
```

Comment: Thanks. Am getting an unexpected EOF while parsing after x:. Would the columns need to be named mon and num, or would just plugging in the names of the arrays would do?

Comment: @ktan can you post the exact error? That sounds like a `SyntaxError`, not anything execution-related. And no, the variables `mon` and `num` don't have any significance to the names of the columns, you could name those two variables anything

Comment: for months, profit_taxed in table:
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @ktan were you trying to type this in line-by-line into a REPL such as IDLE? If you want to run this code in IDLE the way you are trying, you have to put the entire block corresponding to the for loop as a single input

Comment: actually I was executing this chunk by chunk -- it's worked after I've selected many chunks before it. Thanks!!!

Comment: @ktan ok great, no problem

Comment: Actually if I might follow up with another question. If I'd like to print the corresponding element in str for the element in the numbers array with the highest value, how might I do it? I've tried: where max(float(num): but am getting nowhere..

Comment: @ktan would you want to do this inside of the same for loop or on a separate line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214040/discussion-between-ktan-and-awarrier99).

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the number as floats with `astype()` which will allow your comparison.

```
import numpy as np

table = np.array([['Jan', '1765.869'],
 ['Feb', '1337.9730000000002'],
 ['Mar', '-2595.4530000000004'],
 ['Apr', '-2040.0169999999996'],
 ['May', '-419.944'],
 ['Jun', '5085.668'],
 ['Jul', '5747.385'],
 ['Aug', '2761.479'],
 ['Sep', '2329.8729999999996'],
 ['Oct', '-1567.055000000001'],
 ['Nov', '461.71999999999895'],
 ['Dec', '8140.678']])

table[table[:,1].astype(float) > 100][:,0]

#array(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Nov', 'Dec'],dtype='<U19')
```

If you are doing a lot of mixed type work like this, you might find pandas a lot more convenient.

Comment: Thanks. It's weird that I don't see a comma after each square bracket pairing in my table. I'd created it using np.concatenate of two np ndarrays. Any idea why?

Comment: @ktan if you printed it out, that's just how `numpy` displays the array. It's still a valid array, you just need the commas for defining it in your code

Comment: @ktan it's the difference between the `str()` and `repr()` of the array. You can print like `print(repr(table))` to get the commas.